# Download SharePoint Content using Graph Api in C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I have successfully created an app registration and can query SharePoint with the access token generated. a file, `Panda.jpg` is located within SharePoint in the following location,

https://my-host.sharepoint.com/sites/ActiveSite/DocumentLirabry/ParentFolder/ImmediateFolder/Panda.JPG

Where the below mentioned values are static (Text value),

`my-host`
`ActiveSite`
`DocumentLibrary`
`ParentFolder`
`ImmediateFolder`

however their individual ids are not known. i intend to download the Panda.jpg file.

i have looked at official [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) and associated graph [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onedrive?view=graph-rest-1.0) too. Both of the documents suggest to get the id of the relevant resource (site/document-library etc). As a result i'd have to a make series of API calls to get hold of ids until i reach the file in question. Is there any way to directly query the path with text value and download the file.

I also tried [PnP.Framework](https://github.com/pnp/pnpframework) sdk with .net 6.0 to download the file but there seems to be no way to call SharePoint using app registration from Azure active directory. their documentation suggests, for the below code, app needs to be created directly within SharePoint.

```
var context = new PnP.Framework.AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(siteUrl, clientId, clientSecret)
```

Finally if i do need to query with Id, is there any way I can get hold of the ids of sp items, within sharepoint so that i can save them as configuration?

Comment: You can try .NET SDK for Graph: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet

Comment: i can use it but i would still have to make those 3-4 calls to get to the file in question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [driveitem-get-conten](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)t to download files from sharepoint.

```
GET /sites/{site-id}/drives/{drive-id}/root:/{path-relative-to-root}:/content  
GET /sites/{site-id}/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/content
```

Comment: how do i get the `site-id` and `drive-id`? would you mind converting the above link and show how the url would look like in your solution?